# How to return bits from Byte

Tags: c#

Seems elementary but I am not sure how to get each bit from a byte.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As RyuuGan already posted you should go with the [BitArrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx). You just put the data in it by calling the constructor with the wanted elements.

```
byte[] myBytes = new byte[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray( myBytes );
```

Afterwards the instance has some interesting properties to easily access each bit. At first you can just call the index operator to get or set the state of each bit:

```
bool bit = bitArray[4];
bitArray[2] = true;
```

Also you can enumerate over all bits by just using a foreach loop (or any LINQ-stuff you like)

```
foreach (var bit in bitArray.Cast<bool>())
{
    Console.Write(bit + " ");
}
```

To get back from the bits to some specific type (e.g. int) is a little bit trickier, but is quite easy using this extension methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IList<TResult> GetBitsAs<TResult>(this BitArray bits) where TResult : struct
    {
        return GetBitsAs<TResult>(bits, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the bits from an BitArray as an IList combined to the given type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TResult">The type of the result.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="bits">An array of bit values, which are represented as Booleans.</param>
    /// <param name="index">The zero-based index in array at which copying begins.</param>
    /// <returns>An read-only IList containing all bits combined to the given type.</returns>
    public static IList<TResult> GetBitsAs<TResult>(this BitArray bits, int index) where TResult : struct
    {
        var instance = default(TResult);
        var type = instance.GetType();
        int sizeOfType = Marshal.SizeOf(type);

        int arraySize = (int)Math.Ceiling(((bits.Count - index) / 8.0) / sizeOfType);
        var array = new TResult[arraySize];

        bits.CopyTo(array, index);

        return array;
    }
}
```

With this in place you can just get out of it with this single line of code:

```
IList<int> result = bitArray.GetBitsAs<int>();
```

Answer (score 3):

The bits are "numbered" 0 to 7 from right to left. So to get the 5th bit, you'd use `byte & (1<<5)`
I'm sure there's a clearer way of explaining this >_>

EDIT: This would work in an `IF` statement, but if you want just the 1 or 0 specifically, use winwaed's solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

```
byte[] myBytes = new byte[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
BitArray myBA3 = new BitArray( myBytes );
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 Convert.ToString (value, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the bit shift.

Eg. Bit 3:  b = (value >> 3) & 1;

The final and masks bit 1.
if you want Boolean, just compare (==) the above with the value 1.

Comment: Bit 3 is zero referenced. Ie. The lowest value bit is bit 0. For one byte, the highest would be 7