# Adding byte[] interpreted as a number and short

Tags: c#, java, arrays

I want to add a byte array to a short var.
Can any one suggest how to do using bit wise operators.

For example:

```
byte[] a = new byte[] { 0x02,0x11 };  //Dec eq is 529

short b = 10;
```

I want the result to be 539.

Comment: this isn't c++, this is C# (I guess) :)

Comment: is this c# or java or any number of other languages? whatever it is please tag it as such

Comment: There's no hex involved at all. Nor any bitwise operation (at least not in the only solution proposed so far).

Comment: Is this one of those homework questions that prohibits you from using `+` or `+=`?

Comment: Hi , I was trying this in java card .I forgot to check inbuilt API's before posting. There is a function Util.makeShort(byte1,byte2) which returns short. Its working fine now. Thanks for yous suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
b += ((short) a[0]) << 8;
b += a[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have a byte array and not a [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx), but maybe [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181106/how-to-return-bits-from-byte/4183458#4183458).

Answer (score -2):

```
        short c = (short)(BitConverter.ToInt16(a, 0) + b);
```